# r : Why is removeSparseTerms() not doing anything?

Tags: r, data-mining, text-mining, data-cleaning

Why is removeSparseTerms() is not removing any terms?  The words with a single occurrence (etc.) should be removed.
(r V. 3.2)

```
> docs <- tm_map(docs, stemDocument)
> dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(docs)
> freq <- colSums(as.matrix(dtm))
> ord <- order(freq)
> freq[tail(ord)]
one experi   will   can lucid dream
287   312   363   452   1018   2413
> freq[head(ord)]
abbey abdomin   abdu abraham absent   abus
1       1       1       1       1       1
> dim(dtm)
[1]   1 5265
> dtms <- removeSparseTerms(dtm, 0.1)
> dim(dtms)
[1]   1 5265
> dtms <- removeSparseTerms(dtm, 0.001)
> dim(dtms)
[1]   1 5265
> dtms <- removeSparseTerms(dtm, 0.9)
> dim(dtms)
[1]   1 5265
>
```

(The corpus is a single document, the text version of a book.)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you have only one document, so sparseness doesn't change as you change the threshold.  Run these lines and you will see the effect:

```
data("crude")
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude)
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(crude[1]) # pick only the first article (document, like your chapter)
dim(dtm)
(twenty <- removeSparseTerms(dtm, 0.2))
(forty <- removeSparseTerms(dtm, 0.4))
(sixty <- removeSparseTerms(dtm, 0.6))
```

Comment: Does this also explain why findAssocs() doesn't work?
> findAssocs(dtm, "lucid", corlimit=0.2)
$data
numeric(0) --
If I split the book in half, can I then determine what words occur to together, or is the result about how the words compare between the two halfs?
>

Comment: As you show, it doesn't work with a single document.  So I guess it must be done manually...  (If you want to delete the terms used only once.)

Comment: Can you break your book into chapters and then have sparseness work?